# Queries in loop taking too much time to execute

Tags: php, ajax, database, loops

I am trying to update data with Ajax and PHP. The following script updating data, But its taking too much time to run.
**PHP**

```
$groupId = $_POST['group_id'];
$Id_array = $_POST['Id'];
$result_array = $_POST['result'];

$data = array();
if(count($_POST['data']) > 0 && !empty ($_POST['data'])){  
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $array){
        $row = array();
        $row['team_id'] = intval($array['team_id']);
        $row['Note'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['Note'])));
        $data[$key] = $row;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($Id_array); $i++) {
        $Id = intval($Id_array[$i]);
        $result = strip_tags(trim(strval($result_array[$i])));

        $sql1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE teams SET result = :result WHERE id = :id ");
        foreach($data as $key => $array){
            $sql1 ->execute(array(':result' => $result, ':id' => $Id));
        }


        $sql2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE teams SET note = :note WHERE team_id = :teamid AND group_id = :group_id");

        foreach($data as $key => $array){
            $sql2->execute(array(':note' => $array['Note'], ':teamid' => $array['team_id'], ':group_id' => $groupId ));
        }
```

**Network Timing**
[image]

Comment: You might have to do some timing and logging on each query or loop. How many rows are you updating at once? The first query should be optimized since you're updating by id (which I'm guessing is your primary key), but the second may be slow if you don't have an index on team_id and group_id.

Comment: Can you please execute this script without second query?

Comment: @Shujaat yes its causing no problem with 1 query.

Comment: @aynber I am updating 1 row per id on first query, And on query2 it should be multiple rows

Comment: Try moving the `$sql1 = $db->prepare` and `$sql2 = $db->prepare` statements outside of the `for(){}` loop. You only need to prepare once and execute multiple times.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That's true, but it's unlikely to make a big difference. The bottleneck is almost certainly in executing the queries.

Comment: What is the purpose of running `$sql1 ->execute(array(':result' => $result, ':id' => $Id));` inside of the `foreach(){}` loop? You use none of the foreach values...

Comment: @Barmar True, but I am pretty sure that they have enough little problems to add up to a big problem so doing things efficiently from the get-go could help to avoid unknowns.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus because i have multiple id(s) to update at a time.

Comment: okay...read my question again, read your block of code, and let me know if your comment `because i have multiple id(s) to update at a time` is being achieved in the block of code which I mentioned.

Comment: @KoiToHoga You're talking about the `for($i = 0; $i < count($Id_array); $i++)` loop. MonkeyZeus is asking about the loop `foreach ($data as $key => $array)` loop. You don't use `$key` or `$array` inside that loop, you keep doing the same update over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need this loop:

```
    foreach($data as $key => $array){
        $sql1 ->execute(array(':result' => $result, ':id' => $Id));
    }
```

It's updating the same ID repeatedly, since `$Id` doesn't change in the loop. Just do:

```
    $sql1->execute(array(':result' => $result, ':id' => $Id));
```

once.

You can also get some small improvements by doing:

```
$sql1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE teams SET result = :result WHERE id = :id ");
$sql2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE teams SET note = :note WHERE team_id = :teamid AND group_id = :group_id");
```

just once, before any of the loops.

Another problem is that you have this loop:

```
    foreach($data as $key => $array){
        $sql2->execute(array(':note' => $array['Note'], ':teamid' => $array['team_id'], ':group_id' => $groupId ));
    }
```

inside the `for()` loop, but it doesn't use any of the variables that change each time through the loop. So it's re-executing all the same queries for each ID in `$Id_array`.

Take it out of the loop.

With all these changes, the code now looks like:

```
$groupId = $_POST['group_id'];
$Id_array = $_POST['Id'];
$result_array = $_POST['result'];

$sql1 = $db->prepare("UPDATE teams SET result = :result WHERE id = :id ");
$sql2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE teams SET note = :note WHERE team_id = :teamid AND group_id = :group_id");

$data = array();
if(count($_POST['data']) > 0 && !empty ($_POST['data'])){  
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $array){
        $row = array();
        $row['team_id'] = intval($array['team_id']);
        $row['Note'] = strip_tags(trim(strval($array['Note'])));
        $data[$key] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($Id_array as $i => $Id) {
        $Id = intval($Id);
        $result = strip_tags(trim(strval($result_array[$i])));
        $sql1 ->execute(array(':result' => $result, ':id' => $Id));
    }

    foreach($data as $key => $array){
        $sql2->execute(array(':note' => $array['Note'], ':teamid' => $array['team_id'], ':group_id' => $groupId ));
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it worked by removing `foreach($data as $key => $array){}` the timing is decreased, Its now taking 2 to 3 sec to execute. could it be improved more?

Comment: So, first you denounce my comments and then decide to make an answer out of them, tsk tsk tsk. Lol, idc to be honest so have an upvote

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I only said that taking prepare out of the loop is a minor improvement, I never denounced any of your other comments. I even tried to clarify one of them.

Comment: @KoiToHoga I've updated the answer to show another improvement, which may be the biggest one.

Comment: Yes, Thank you Barmar. It helped me alot, Now its taking less than a second to update.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a transaction instead of auto committing in a loop.
So,

```
//PDO::beginTransaction ( void )
$dbh->beginTransaction();
foreach () {
    $smt->exec();
}
//PDO::commit ( void )
$dbh->commit();
```

Also, you only need to prepare a statement one time since you're binding your variables in the execute function, so try keeping any prepare statements out of a loop.

This should help with some of the overhead of the query in the loop.